# What is the difference between Minecraft java edition and bedrock edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, version-differences, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I have just recently started playing Minecraft again after a 4 or 5 year hiatus (java edition ~v1.8 apparently), so I have a couple questions:

1. **What's the difference between Minecraft Java Edition and Minecraft Bedrock Edition?**
2. **Does it cost money? and is it worth it?**
3. **How are the servers different in Java vs Bedrock Edition?**
4. **Any other notable changes since v.1.8ish?**
5. **What are the most popular servers to hop on nowadays?**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you have ever owned Java Edition, you should still be able to play it without paying any additional money, but you might have to migrate your Mojang account to a Microsoft account and/or [recover your Mojang account](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360029681732-Having-Trouble-Accessing-Your-Account-) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The official documentation and support pages can answer Question #1:**

- https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/java-or-bedrock-edition
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/differencesbetweenbedrockandjava

---

The biggest difference between the two is that Bedrock Edition runs on Windows 10/11, Console, Mobile, and VR, while Java Edition runs on Windows, Mac, and Linux. The two editions cannot crossplay, making Bedrock more flexible for multiplayer with different devices.

There are some other major differences, reference the above links to read more. The documentation provides a more technical view while the blog article is more player-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

May I redirect you to this comparison on the Microsoft page?
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/differencesbetweenbedrockandjava

Comment: This question only answers one of the questions put forward. Granted the question may or may not be well-composed, but please either try to answer the entire question, or specifically say which question you are answering. Welcome to Arqade!

Comment: @AdamRaichu 'May or may not be well-composed' ? I mentioned that I haven't played Minecraft for 4 or 5 years. There was no bedrock edition then. If I played it 4 or 5 years ago I must've paid for it, so not sure why you're confused about what costs money.

Answer (score -1):

1. Minecraft Java Edition is for PC, MAC, and Linux devices. Minecraft Bedrock Edition is for consoles, Windows, and mobile devices.
2. Does what cost money? Minecraft is not free, but you can play a really old version of the game free at [classic.minecraft.net](http://classic.minecraft.net).
3. There are several differences in servers because of differences between versions. For example, there is a command called /scoreboard that is way more sophisticated on JE than BE.
4. There have been many changes since 1.8. The current version is 1.17. Some major changes include shields, Netherite tools/weapons (which are not all standard crafting recipes), addition of copper and amethyst, addition of trees, new biomes, and new structures to the nether, piglins and hoglins, and many more.

If you're looking to quickly learn about recent changes, I would suggest you watch a couple beginner tutorials made recently (regardless of your skill level) to become familiar with new mechanics such as shields, new ores (and where they generate), and other major updates to the nether and overworld. Do note that in 1.18 the y limits will be changed from 0-256 to a larger size (including negative numbers) so any mechanics you learn now may change this holiday season.

5. This is an opinion based question and therefore I cannot answer accurately. However, Googling this question consistently returns [Hypixel](https://hypixel.net/).

---

For more general information on Minecraft and recent changes, see [minecraft.wiki](http://minecraft.wiki).

Comment: Can owners of the Java edition still redeem a copy of Bedrock?  If the OP has an account and played 1.8, presumably they would fall into the correct time range for that to be valid. And I’m guessing “is it worth it” refers to whether Bedrock is worth it, though I could be wrong. I’m just not sure whether that offer is still valid.

Comment: This is an [article](https://www.windowscentral.com/mojang-offers-more-free-copies-minecraft-windows-10-java-edition-owners) that outlines Mojang's offer. However, based on the date of comments, it was posted early 2020 so may no longer be valid. I don't own Java Edition so I won't be able to check.